# Expecting EOF found if

Tags: java, lambda, compiler-errors, file-handling, checkstyle

Hi I am stuck in the below problem where I got a checkstyle exception in `if(files !=null)`. So it is also not compilable.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
private void printBeforeData(final int svrID, final PrintStream ps, final File dir) throws RemoteException {

    // 「p[サーバID].csv」は、メモリ上のデータを使用して生成するので、除く
    final String regexField = ELECTRIC_FILE + svrID + "\\.csv\\.[0-9]+$";
    final File[] files =  dir.listFiles((final File dirToFilter, final String filename) ->
        filename.matches(regexField));
    if (files != null) {
        // 昇順でソート
        final List<File> listFiles1 = Arrays.asList(files);
        Collections.sort(listFiles1, (f1, f2)
                -> ElectricPowerManager.getSuffixNo(f1) - ElectricPowerManager.getSuffixNo(f2));
        final StringBuilder strings = new StringBuilder();
        for (final File file: listFiles1) {
            try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath())) {
                int cnt = 0;
                for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                    strings.append(line);
                    strings.append(LINE_BREAK);
                    cnt++;
                    if (cnt == CASH_ROW) {
                        // 一定数溜め込んでからファイル出力
                        ps.print(strings.toString());
                        strings.delete(0, strings.length());
                        cnt = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (cnt > 0) {
                    ps.print(strings.toString());
                    strings.delete(0, strings.length());
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                core.putSystemLog(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "#" + METHOD_PRINT_BEFORE_DATA +
                        " Failed print Electric Data. serverID:" + svrID, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you pasted all of your code? There is a closing brace missing at the end (the closing brace of the `printBeforeData()` method).

Comment: Hi Martin I missed a brace while pasting code from IDE

Comment: You need to put the exact compiler or program output in your question as it isn't evident at the moment what the problem is.

Comment: What version of CheckStyle are you using?

Comment: Hi Martin I am unable to find it .These checkstyle setting given by client to us

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is a bug in CheckStyle, so if you can upgrade it you should do so.

Answer (score 0):

`final File[] files =  dir.listFiles((final File dirToFilter, final String filename) - filename.matcheS(regexField));`

1) Nobody (neither the compiler nor you) understand what it means to substract a boolean from a list of parameters (the `- filename.matcheS(regexField))`). Think again what you are trying to do.

2) You are defining variables (`final File`, `final String`) in the middle of a parameter list, you should use expressions here (like an already already defined and with a value set elsewhere, or constants). I bet you are confusing method invocation with definition (or you just forgot to complete the code that the IDE autogenerated).